# Default function parameter value in safari is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I am using angularjs, and having problem with `null` assignment in safari only. Its working in chrome and firefox.

```
$scope.submit = function(id=null){
}
```

I am getting this error

```
SyntaxError: Expected token ')'
```

when I remove `null`, It just works. I don't know why !

```
$scope.submit = function(id){
}
```

Please help me to understand why this happening only with safari ?

Comment: Default function parameter values are an ES2015 feature that Safari apparently does not support.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) from ES2015 are not yet supported in Safari. Please check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters#Browser_compatibility).

At the moment the basic support provide Chrome 49 and Firefox 15.

---

But you can use the following ES5 code to achieve the same:

```
$scope.submit = function(id) {
  if (id === undefined) {
    id = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , do you know any alternative for this please ?

Comment: Thank you again :)