# Safari browser-specific error (optional argument)

Tags: javascript, html, safari

So I have the following error which only occur in Safari (Apple product, go figure) while not occurring in Chrome or Firefox (code runs perfectly).

Error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='. Expected a ')' or a ',' after a parameter declaration.`

This is erroring for: `function ajax_general(url, params, title="")`

When I remove the optional argument, it runs. Otherwise this occurs. How should I change this to make it also run on Safari?

Comment: this has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841496/default-function-parameter-value-in-safari-is-not-working

Comment: @knobcreekman thanks, I expected it to be answered already, but I still couldn't google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using default function parameters which are not supported by safari currently. Your function:

```
function ajax_general(url, params, title="")
```

> Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized
>   with default values if no value or undefined is passed.

```
title=""
```

...is essentially saying, "If no title argument is passed, set title to empty string."

If the third parameter must be set to a value, do it like so:

```
function ajax_general(url, params, "")
```

Or depending on your use case, do it inside/outside the function:

```
var title = "";
function ajax_general(url, params, title);
```

Chrome and Firefox both have support for default function parameters, but safari unfortunately does not.

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters