# Syntax error in only Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I'm getting a syntax error `expected token ')'` in only Safari. I've found some posts on the forum saying that `default parameters` aren't supported in Safari. 
But how can I fix this then with the code below?

```
function showCartMessage(message = '', img_url = '', statusClass = ''){
    if(img_url == ''){
        $('.cart-message .product_notification_background').css('background', 'whitesmoke');
    }else{
        $('.cart-message .product_notification_background').css('background', 'url("' + img_url + '") no-repeat center center');
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript function arguments can only have default values in browsers that support ES6. To make this work reliably cross-browser, remove the `= ''` in the function definition

Comment: Taka a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841496/default-function-parameter-value-in-safari-is-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply default inside the function:

```
function showCartMessage(message, img_url, statusClass){
    message = message || '';
    img_url = image_url ||'';
    statusClass = statusClass || '';

    if(img_url == ''){
        $('.cart-message .product_notification_background').css('background', 'whitesmoke');
    }else{
        $('.cart-message .product_notification_background').css('background', 'url("' + img_url + '") no-repeat center center');
    }
}
```

So this way, any parameter coming through as `undefined` will be made a blank string.